# TestCafe: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ModuleName' before initialization

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, preloading

Im using testcafe for testing our page for now bout 1 year.
On the latest version of our page, the devs used preloading and critical CSS for performance optimizations.

Since then i get an error on page startup:

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ModuleName' before initialization`

Is there a problem with TestCafe if a a page uses rel="modulepreload" to import js?

The DOM shows, that this module is part of a js-file that is preloaded like this.
`<link href="//cdn.test.local/version1/dist/script/something.static.js" rel="modulepreload">`

-> link wont work since the page is on a local site.

Content of js-file:
`import{ModuleName}from'./classes/something.class.ajax.js';export const someAjaxPlugin=new ModuleName;`

This Error does only occur if i run the page in testcafe... is that a bug?
Any one an idea what i can do so my tests will run again?

Comment: Addition: It seems to work in Firefox, but not in Chrome/Edge...

Comment: Please check if you can reproduce the problem with the latest TestCafe version. If it persists, I suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) in the TestCafe GitHub repository and share a reproducible example with the team.

Comment: my version of vscode is the latest and it also happens on latest insider-build.

problem seems to be connected with the location of the CDN.
If i use a local (same domain) version of the CDN that hosts the files it works just fine.

If i use the official public cnd version to test it doesn't work files are the same, so i suppose it could have to to with a sort of timing problem.


..i guess i gonna create an issue, thanx.

Comment: Issue posted: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6838